# How do I test a UART Receiver designed in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, uart

I have been working to design a UART in vhdl
How do I test it though?
I have tested the transmitter using TeraTerm. Is it possible to send data using Tera Term as well? If yes, could you tell me how?

Comment: that's not a helpful answer
I tried typing in but it does not show up
Do I need to set any configurations?

Comment: You might. Temporarily turn on local echo (to see what you're typing). Also turn off flow control which may inhibit transmission.

Comment: Do you have a simulator?  Use a testbench in the simulator to drive a couple of UART waveforms to the your UART design.  This will simplify your ability to see what correctly receives the UART word and what does not.  Synthesizing the chip and connecting it to hardware only works when you can correctly access what is and what is not working correctly.

Comment: In extension to Jim's answer: instantiate the UART twice in your simulation and send some data from UART1 to UART2. In this way you can send and receive bytes rather then bits and you can test RX and TX in one step. You may use `rx <= tx'delayed (50 ns);` to simulate some wire delay. You should also drive your UARTs with different independent clocks.